# How can this prepositional phrase be parsed?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Amaranta would sigh, laugh, and dream of a second homeland of handsome men and beautiful women who spoke a childlike language, **with ancient cities of whose past grandeur only the cats among the rubble remained**. (One Hundred Years of Solitude, tr. by Gregory Rabassa)

The preposition phrase seems like having a small clause [or a verbless clause]. But it’s not easy to identify which is the subject and which is the predicate. And I wonder why ‘of’ is there –– when there isn’t ‘of’, can’t the phrase make sense?
([(1) with ancient cities][(2) of whose past grandeur][(3) only the cats among the rubble remained]: The first bracket seems to be modified by relative clause (2+3). (2) is the subject and (4) the predicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *wh-* relative clause.

The entire predicate of the underlying sentence is *remained*.

The prepositional phrase *of their past grandeur* is a constituent of the *only PART of WHOLE* construction which constitutes the subject. Compare

> Only part          of the whole            remained.
>   Only three          of the original ten      remained.
>   Only the cats in the rubble of their past grandeur remained.

But placing the *of WHOLE* piece there is ambiguous - it looks as if it modifies *rubble*; and it is a "heavy" phrase; so we ordinarily move that to the beginning or the end of the sentence, leaving the head of the subject as close as possible to the verb:

> Only the cats in the rubble remained of their past grandeur.
>   Of their past grandeur only the cats in the rubble remained.

To accommodate the relative clause, we employ the second version, with *of their* at the front, and replace *their* with *whose*:

> ...of whose past grandeur only the cats in the rubble remained.